# Is there any possibilities to avoid the server restart after updating the keystore at WSO2 ESB 6.6.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have an annoying problem: one of the resources I integrate with, changes ssl certificate ones a month, so I have to reboot the server every time and it's not quite cool...

I hope someone can share an experience how to avoid this. Of course, if it's possible at all.
Tnx, a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can configure *axis2.xml* according to the documentation of [Multi-HTTPS Transport Dynamic SSL profiles](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Multi-HTTPS+Transport#Multi-HTTPSTransport-DynamicSSLprofiles). As you see there is functionality like **Loading SSL profiles dynamically at runtime**, and i believe that should also reload the keystore file.